# github push origin

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have some trouble pushing some changes to a branch on GitHub. I am quite new to Git and I am sure either I made something silly or I missed seomthing obvious, but I can't see what.

I made a fresh clone of one of my repos (actually a fork on GitHub), then switch to an existing branch, made some changes, and committed them.  All I want is to push them back to GitHub. But "git push" says "Everything up-to-date", even though "git status" says that my local branch is ahead of the origin's branch by one commit:

```
> git checkout -b mystuff origin/newstuff
Switched to a new branch 'mystuff'

> echo "Make some changes..." >> file.txt

> git commit -m "Change." file.txt
[...]

> git status
# On branch mystuff
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/newstuff' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

> git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Any idea what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin mystuff
```

Just `git push` will push on the default branch, which is usually set as `master`.

Extra tip: the `-u` option for `git push` will set a new default branch, so if you run

```
git push -u origin mystuff
```

you can subsequently just do `git push` and push on `mystuff` without specifying the branch anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele.  I've seen this command when I read looking for a solution.  But if I remember well, this will create a new branch `mystuff` on origin, instead of pushing it to `newstuff` (the original branch), isn't it?  If this is not possible, I would rather create a new branch with another name then, if possible.

Comment: actually I think since you binded `mystuff` to `origin/newstuff` at the moment of creation, it should behave the way you want already.

Comment: OK, I tried, and it created a new branch `mystuff` on origin. Not a big deal, at least it is on GitHub now, and I'll be able to make a pull request.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can try something like `git push origin/newstuff mystuff`